# dynamic import component inside another using path in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, components, lazy-loading, react-dom

I am new to react. I have a task for importing a component inside another one dynamically.
as you can see I have an AutoComplete component that uses `react-select`; what I want is when user searches for a value and the value is not provided by the list, the user clicks on `Create ...` option and a dialog opens containing the needed component ( the component need to by imported at that time). Now I am passing the component as child but I want it more dynamic like passing the path of Component as prop and the AutoComplete loads by the path. any solution?

sample component uses AutoComplete:

```js
<Autocomplete
  apiUrl="/coreums/api/provinces"
  onChange={(field, value) => {
    console.log(`${field}  ${value}`);
  }}
  onCreate={(field) => {
    console.log(field);
  }}
  name="province"
  componentName=""
  entity={null}
>
  {/* <ProvinceUpdate></ProvinceUpdate> */}
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</Autocomplete>
```

as you see I am passing a `h1` and it renders but for another component like ProvinceUpdater just want to pass my components path and it will be rendered.
which changes need my AutoComplete?
here is my AutoComplete:

```js
import React, {
  Component,
  FC,
  Suspense,
  lazy,
  useEffect,
  useState,
} from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';
import Select from 'react-select';

import { AvForm } from 'availity-reactstrap-validation';
import { Button } from 'primereact/button';
import { Dialog } from 'primereact/dialog';

interface Props {
  name: string;
  apiUrl: string;
  entity: any;
  filterBy?: string;
  onChange: (field: string, value: any) => void;
  onCreate: (field: string) => void;
  componentName?: string;
}

const Autocomplete: FC<Props> = ({
  name,
  apiUrl,
  entity,
  onChange,
  children,
  onCreate,
  filterBy = 'name',
  componentName,
}) => {
  const [myOptions, setMyOptions] = useState([]);
  const [childDialogVisible, setChildDialogVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get(`services/${apiUrl}?cacheBuster=${new Date().getTime()}`).then(
      (res) => {
        // console.log(res)
        setMyOptions(
          res.data.map((obj) => {
            return { value: obj.id, label: obj[filterBy] };
          })
        );
      }
    );
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (newValue: any, actionMeta: any) => {
    if (newValue) onChange(name, newValue.value);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (inputValue: any, actionMeta: any) => {
    Axios.get(
      `services/${apiUrl}?name.contains=${inputValue}&cacheBuster=${new Date().getTime()}`
    ).then((res) => {
      setMyOptions(
        res.data.map((obj) => {
          return { value: obj.id, label: obj.name };
        })
      );
    });
  };

  const handleCreate = (inputValue) => {
    setChildDialogVisible(true);
    onCreate(inputValue);
  };

  const renderFooter = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          label="No"
          icon="pi pi-times"
          onClick={() => setChildDialogVisible(false)}
          className="p-button-text"
        />
        <Button
          label="Yes"
          icon="pi pi-check"
          onClick={() => setChildDialogVisible(false)}
          autoFocus
        />
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <CreatableSelect
        options={myOptions}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onCreateOption={handleCreate}
        onInputChange={handleInputChange}
        menuPortalTarget={document.body}
      />

      <Dialog
        header="Header"
        visible={childDialogVisible}
        style={{ width: '50vw' }}
        footer={renderFooter()}
        onHide={() => setChildDialogVisible(false)}
      >
        <Suspense fallback={() => <p>Loading</p>}>{children}</Suspense>
      </Dialog>
    </>
  );
};

export default Autocomplete;
```

Comment: you can try React.lazy function: const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import(path));

Comment: How can I use path as prop there?

Comment: In the params of the function Autocomplete, you will add the property path.

Comment: when i call lazy loading inside function Autocomplete it stucks in a loop. so I can't call that inside function body